# Chart showing common smartphone and tablet screen resolutions?

Tags: html, browser, tablet, smartphone

Google has the wonderful browser size page showing screen resolutions and the percentage of users using them:

http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/

That probably is for all web access.  What about for smartphones?  Is there something similar but only showing smartphones (and tablets)?

Comment: Statistics like these are only really useful if you measure them for the market demographic of the individual website where you are going to make decisions based on those statistics. One website might have 2% of it's traffic running at a 3.5" screen, while another might see more than 90% of it's traffic with that screen size. You should install some tracking software on your own website, to find out what size screen it's users have.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such information being available for the entire web, but you could always collect it for your own site.

This has recently become very easy with [google analytics new feature.](http://techcrunch.com/2012/06/04/google-analytics-now-lets-you-conduct-browser-size-analysis/)